# Polymorphic function

Tags: scala, apache-spark, polymorphism

I have a `Dataset[Edge]` where each edge is an edge from a parent entity to a child entity. With the function below I want to make a mapping from `parent_id` to its child entity.

The child entities can be of different types, for example Officer (of a company), Intermediary (of a company), Address (of a company, officer or intermediary)

```scala
def mapParentIDtoEntity[T](edges: Dataset[Edge], entities: Dataset[T])(implicit tag: TypeTag[T]) = {
  edges
    .joinWith(
      entities,
      edges("child_id") ==== entities("id"),
      "left"
    )
    .map(
      case (edge: Edge, entity: T) => edge.parent_id -> entity
    )
}
```

My problem has to do with type erasure. I have already added `(implicit tag: TypeTag[T])` to make sure that Spark is able to encode `T`, but I am still having the error below:

```
abstract type T in type pattern reflect.runtime.universe.TypeTag[T] (the underlying of tag.type) 
is unchecked since it is eliminated by erasure
          case (edge: Edge, entity: T) => edge.parent_id -> entity
```

Could anyone explain why this still happens, and how I can fix it?

Comment: You need an encoder not a tag.

Answer (score 0):

The following code compiles (with implicit `Encoder[(Int, T)]` instead of `TypeTag[T]`)

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.{Dataset, Encoder}

case class Edge(parent_id: Int)

def mapParentIDtoEntity[T](edges: Dataset[Edge], entities: Dataset[T](implicit 
  enc: Encoder[(Int, T)]
) = {
  edges
    .joinWith(
      entities,
      edges("child_id") === entities("id"),
      "left"
    )
    .map {
      case (edge: Edge, entity: T) => edge.parent_id -> entity
    }
}
```